# React native 0.63.4 ios 14 no static images

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode12

I try to build a release with Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) and react native 0.63.4 and local images are not shown but url images are.

I found many topics and solutions about that but nothing work, i'm stuck for 3 days.

- I have this warning for each images of my project:

  [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
- My main.jsbundle and assets folder are in the same folder and listed in Xcode -> Build phases -> Copy Bundle Ressources
- [The bug with RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container#issuecomment-658244428) on ios 14 is supposed to be resolved due to my react native version > 0.62.2 (i checked the file too and everythings ok)
- I tried

  <Image source={{ uri: Image.resolveAssetSource(Logo)}}

But i'm unable to correctly build a release on real device, simulator or archiving it on testflight. Debug mode is working fine. What i'm missing ??

Comment: Have you added the else block in file react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

Comment: Have you read my post ? react native 0.62.2 fixed that and i checked anyway

Comment: @Jigneshmayani I forgot to precise, i have this error for each images of my project: [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'

Comment: Possible duplicate (also with no answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529743/local-image-is-not-being-rendered-in-release-and-testflight

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this a while ago, check out [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-657201709).

1. go to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m`
2. find

```
   if (_currentFrame) { 
     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale; 
     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage; 
   }
```

3. and replace with

```
 if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please read the OP. It clearly states this is not the problem in bullet point 3.