# Local image is not being rendered in release and TestFlight

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using react-native v0.63.4, and all the local image load fine in development mode

```
<Image
    source={require('../assets/images/xyz.png')}
    style={styles.img}
    resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

but once we built it in release mode or test flight, all the image loaded with `require` is not being rendered.

What I have found so far:

1. Doesn't seem to be https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29268, since I am using 0.63.4
2. Examined the IPA file, and it does contain all the images

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate (also with no answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239089/react-native-0-63-4-ios-14-no-static-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of (has an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying/35366243#35366243

Comment: @Kolby, didn't find a solution, but I got a workaround, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31525#issuecomment-845345482

Comment: @NirajNiroula Thanks, but those answers and related to the previous missing image problem linked in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This can be linking issue

In Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images replace any lines you have for this:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

After that clean project, delete build folder and run following command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

I hope this is helpful.

Also make sure your asset folder is there in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: I tried with this but not working for me